# display 4 lines of first column to left of the page

Tags: html, css

we have 4 lines displaying like this in [page](http://sb.kidsdial.com/shipping-and-track)

[image]

we want to move all texts of first column to left & keep all 4 colon[`:`] in same line

```
<div class="all-link">
<p>Delivery :</p>
<span><a href="http://www.delhivery.com/ " target="_blank">Delivery.com</a></span>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<p>Parcelled.in:</p>
<span><a href="http://parcelled.in/track" target="_blank">Parcelled.in</a></span>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<p>DTDC:</p>
<span><a href="http://dtdc.in/" target="_blank">DTDC</a></span>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<p>Speed Post:</p>
<span><a href="http://www.indiapost.gov.in/speednettracking.aspx" target="_blank">Speed Post</a></span>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

i am trying with `position : relative & left , right pixels but i need to use lot of code for that.

Comment: You mean all of this text in the same line? Cus if you wanna do that, you should remove those div-s between span-s

Comment: please add your css as well

Comment: no, i want to move all texts of first column to left side @TeutaKoraqi

Comment: @GokulShinde we used inline css only.

Comment: It's tabular data...use a table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ths is really tabular data so an actual `table` would be best but CSS Tables can manage this with a slight HTML structure change.

Wrap each paragraph and associates span in a div and these wrapper can act as table rows.

```css
.all-link {
  display: table;
  margin: 1em;
}

.all-link .row {
  display: table-row;
}

.all-link .row p,
.all-link .row span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: .25em;
  border:1px solid lightgrey;
}

.all-link .row p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-link">
<div class="row">
  <p>Delivery :</p>
  <span><a href="http://www.delhivery.com/ " target="_blank">Delivery.com</a></span>
</div>

<div class="row"><p>Parcelled.in:</p>
  <span><a href="http://parcelled.in/track" target="_blank">Parcelled.in</a></span>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <p>DTDC:</p>
  <span><a href="http://dtdc.in/" target="_blank">DTDC</a></span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <p>Speed Post:</p>
  <span><a href="http://www.indiapost.gov.in/speednettracking.aspx" target="_blank">Speed Post</a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below html, it might help you.

```html
<div class="all-link">
<p style="display: inline-block;margin: 0;text-align: left !important;width: 90px;">Delivery <b style="float:right">:</b></p>
<span><a href="http://www.delhivery.com/ " target="_blank">Delivery.com</a></span>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<p style="display: inline-block;margin: 0;text-align: left !important;width: 90px;">Parcelled.in <b style="float:right">:</b></p>
<span><a href="http://parcelled.in/track" target="_blank">Parcelled.in</a></span>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<p style="display: inline-block;margin: 0;text-align: left !important;width: 90px;">DTDC <b style="float:right">:</b></p>
<span><a href="http://dtdc.in/" target="_blank">DTDC</a></span>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<p style="display: inline-block;margin: 0;text-align: left !important;width: 90px;">Speed Post <b style="float:right">:</b></p>
<span><a href="http://www.indiapost.gov.in/speednettracking.aspx" target="_blank">Speed Post</a></span>
<div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/shipping-and-track) , i updated your code. but didt worked for me

Comment: I have checked your link and found a style assigned to `.all-link > p` this `p` is `text-align: rigth !important`. That's why text not align at left side. I have updated above code. Try this and let me know if still not working.

Comment: i am sorry, as other user gave better answer i accepted that.

Comment: no problem. It is more important that you should get solve your problem